# Guice and non-Singleton Servlets

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, guice, guice-servlet

How we can use non-Singleton servlet or handler in Guice, for example I want to create new instance for every request and immediately destroy it or give it to garbage collector after processing the request.

I dont want to keep ii in memory as singleton or reuse for other future requests.

I think probably somehow by using bind() function,

RGDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [use RequestScope](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Scopes).

I typically use provider methods with scopes, so you would have code that looks like

```
public class FooModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override protected void configure() {
    // set up bindings
  }

  @Provides
  @RequestScoped
  PerRequestObject providePerRequestObject() {
    return new PerRequestObject(...);
  }
}
```

Be sure to [install `ServletModule`](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule) and [setup the `GuiceFilter`](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Servlets) or else this won't work!

Comment: No, my question is how to configure non-singletone Servlet

Comment: I'm confused.  You say "I want to create new instance for every request and immediately destroy it or give it to garbage collector after processing the request. I dont want to keep ii in memory as singleton or reuse for other future requests."  That's exactly what this answer will do.  I don't understand what you mean by "how to configure non-singletone Servlet."  Request scope is per request.  There's no singletons involved.

Comment: my question is how to configure non-singletone Servlet, I want to be created new servlet instance in case of new request when the first is still in process not inside objects used by servlet

Comment: It seems for each servlet class container just create one instance, I want to change it

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried @SessionScoped?